# Android application view containers are sticky

Tags: android, android-layout

I need help, my layouts and containers are lingering on after I have used the code bellow to remove them.

For example I have page 1 that adds a small text that explains how to use the part of the program under scrutiny, and then the next page allows the user to add a name where there is a label with text Name: and a EditText to add the name in next to it.

Both the components 'stick' but the EditText is reproduced multiple times and I have no idea why! I would also like to stop the sticking.

By sticking I simply mean that the view does not leave view like it should(still visible).

Here is some code.

```
        if(pageCount == lastPageCount--)
        {
            page2Layout.removeAllViews();
            //page2Layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            //Reset all text views.
            helpText.setText("");
        }

        helpText.setLayoutParams(params);
        helpText.setText("You cannot view this part sorry :S\n\n" + 
        "You cannot view this part sorry :S.\n" +
        "You cannot view this part sorry :S");
        page1Layout.addView(helpText);

        page1Layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else if(pageNumber == 2)
    {
        if(pageCount == lastPageCount++)
        {
            //page1Layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            page1Layout.removeAllViews();
        }
        else if (pageCount == lastPageCount++)
        {
            page3Layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        //Name Position + Containers etc
        LinearLayout nameLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        nameLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        nameLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
        TextView nameLabel = new TextView(this);
        nameLabel.setLayoutParams(params);
        nameLabel.setText("Name: ");
        EditText nameTextField = new EditText(this);
        nameTextField.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        //All to name layout.
        nameLayout.addView(nameLabel);
        nameLayout.addView(nameTextField);
        page2Layout.addView(nameLayout); 
        page2Layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

Comment: Just a small update, I figured out the main problem is the EditText as the text just seems to duplicate, I cant seem to find any update or refresh for the application to fix the problem.

Comment: I think I may have found it, .clearDisappearingChildren(); should do the trick :D

Comment: False alarm I have not fixed it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beware of the stupid mistakes coders can make when they stare at code too long.

```
    if(pageCount == lastPageCount++)
```

For anyone who is also stuck similarly, lastPageCount++ will increment lastPageCount after the statement has run.

Therefore the wrong code is run.